# How to handle the ID from an actionlink to show this in a readonly textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have a lot of tables. Each table has an incremental int ID and a company guid id.
I made an  with the company guid as id param. Like this:

```
@Html.(@item.Bedrijfsnaam.ToString(), "Edit", "BedrijfsGegevens", new { id = (Guid)item.Bedrijfsnummer }, null)
```

When I click on this  I want to fill a readonly textboxfor on a different view from a different model with this guid.

The guid is passed properly but then.......what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on what, a link? I'm assuming you forgot the .Actionlink in front of that @HTML. If its a link, take a look at the @Ajax.Actionlink method and then on the onsuccess, trigger some javascript/jquery to fill in a div/cell/textbox or whatever you'd like with the data you return.